How to know when a following tail moves from old file to the new one
So, I am working with tail -F ( or tail --follow=filename). Now it works as advertised and when a rollover occurs it will move to the new file.
This is great and helps me keep track of my logs. The issue is I want to know when tail moves from old file to the new one.
The situation is as follows:
I have a huge log file that takes 15 mins to process. Now lets say at minute 5, a rollover occurs. Tail has the file description open, and uses it to complete tailing process and then moves to the new one.
Now I keep a history of which file and which line I have last logged. I do this by increasing the number by the lines processes (its multiprocess program, but what else can I do?).
The issue comes that after the rollover, the new file is starting from line 0, but my line_number has already been increase to 5 million. So, for this new file which has say 100 logs, I'll store the line number as 5,000,100.
I used watchdog to find when the file rolls over to reset the line number to 0, but in case the rollover happens during the initial run, like say at 5minute mark of the 15 min run, then I still end up with a 3mil+ number.
Since line_number is used to continue from where I last left in case the program died accidentally, this can mean loss of data.
Just to note:
I am running this command from python (CPython)

I am not sure my answer works. My concern is the interaction between takes 15 mins to process and rollover. tail -f follows a file descriptor, and will be unaware that the file has been renamed and a new file created. tail -F follows a file name, and your Python will be unaware that the renamed file has not been completely processed. Processing both the remainder of the old file, and the new one, (in that order) seems to need some higher-level integration with the rollover process.

Redirect the stderr from tail to stdout, and deal with the commentary that tail -F provides.
tail -F myLog.txt 2>&1

Your Python code should now receive messages like:
tail: cannot open 'myLog.txt' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: 'myLog.txt' has appeared;  following new file
tail: myLog.txt: file truncated

YMMV: The quotes seem unreliable, and there may be a race condition when the file rolls over. But file truncated should be followed by a new Line 1.

Thanks Paul. This is giving me a good direction to work on.
I tested it out and saw inconsistent behavior. While if the file was at the end, the output is similar (I didn't get the truncated log); I deleted the log file while tailing and renamed its copy. I instead god a line in format: ==> filename <==

@user607688  That line appears for me only with the tail -v option. It confirms the filename it just got hold of. Helpful with -F when a file is created but not yet written to, or when you are tailing several files with a single command (it repeats the filename whenever the active file changes). I forced the truncated as an example with : > myLog.txt, as I am still not sure what your rollover actually does. I found a bunch of about 10 likely stderr messages in the binary with strings -n 8 /usr/bin/tail | grep '^%s.

The rollover would move the old log file to an archived name. Basically, logName.log becomes logName.1.log, logName.1.log becomes logName.2.log and so on up to 10.log where the last one gets removed. I ended up putting a check on ==> filename <== coming twice. Flimsy I know, but till I find something better, this will do.

@user607688  There is a race condition there: tail only reads at intervals (it can use a timer, or inotify if available). Any data logged after the rollover but before tail notices the file has been replaced will not be tailed. I also do not get the ==> file <== message here, as the actual name has not changed: I see only tail: 'myLog' has been replaced;  following new file, or has appeared in the first iteration, so I guess it also checks inodes. (more...)

I dislike the default rollover action. At National Grid (logging 160 servers and workstations on the live SCADA system) I rolled over on date/time with names like 20240409_09:15:00_myHost.log. These were constantly filtered as received against blacklists and whitelists, and then reprocessed in more depth overnight to look for patterns and imminent failures. I even tied this into SMS messaging and out-of-hours support rotas.
